# Multiple DOM Traverse without errors or runtime errors

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to traverse rather complicated structure

First I tried

```
var textFromCLick = $0.closest('span').parentElement.querySelector('label').innerText
```

This works only if the user clicks on elements that has the exact structure.

If the structure is different I get 'Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null'

So I came up with this dirty code

```
if(0$.closest('span') !== null) {
  var el2 = 0$.closest('span');
  if (el2.parentElement.querySelector('label') !== null) {
    textFromCLick = el2.parentElement.querySelector('label').innerText;
  } else {
    textFromCLick = "";
  }
} else { 
  textFromCLick = "";
}
```

This works but.. as you see, the code is too long and inefficient.
How can I make it graceful?

Comment: Not inefficient if it avoids errors. The *if* blocks can be replaced with `&&` but there's no getting around having to test that each expression returns a value that is suitable for the next expression not to throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Chaining method calls is fragile if any call might fail, as in

```
$0.closest('span').parentElement.querySelector('label').innerText;
```

If any part fails, the next part will likely throw an error. So test each part at the point that it might return a value such that the next part throws an error. In this case, various expressions might return either null or something else, so to test each bit:

```
let span = $0.closest('span');
let parent = span && span.parent;
let label = parent && parent.querySelector('label');
let text = label? label.textContent : '';
```

You can probably combine the second and third lines as:

```
let label = span && span.parent.querySelector('label');
```

on the basis that if there is a span (or any element that below the root HTML element), it will have a parent node hence `span.parent` is very unlikely to fail.

An alternative is to wrap the call in *try..catch*, but that's just lazy:

```
let text = '';
try {
  text = $0.closest('span').parentElement.querySelector('label').textContent;
catch (e) {
  text = '';
}
```

A better strategy is to associate elements by some property such as id or class so the relationship isn't structural, e.g.

```js
function findLabel() {
  let label = document.querySelector('label.' + this.className);
  console.log(label && label.textContent);
}

window.onload = ()=>{
  document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(button =>
    button.addEventListener('click', findLabel)
  );
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span>
    <button class="fooBar0">Find my label</button>
  </span>
</p>

<label class="fooBar0">Here I am</label>
```